# How to generate all permutations of length M in array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Let's assume that we have array of length N, and I need to generate all permutations of length M in the array

I tried using next permutation but if I want to generate all permutations of length 3 of array with length 5 I get the permutations only with the first 3 numbers.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int m=3;

    do {
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++) {
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    } while(next_permutation(arr, arr+m));
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want permutations or combinations?

Answer (score 1):

There are faster solutions (see Knuth 4A), but this one is simple and within a linear factor of optimal. The only changes from what you wrote are (1) the `reverse` statement (2) the argument of `next_permutation` (`n` instead of `m`).

```
#include <iostream>

#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  int m = 3;

  do {
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
      cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    reverse(arr + m, arr + 5);
  } while (next_permutation(arr, arr + 5));
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give all sequential permutations:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int m=3;
    int ct = 0;

    do {
    do {
    for(int i=ct;i<ct+m;i++) {
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    } while(next_permutation(arr+ct, arr+ct+m));
    ct++;
    } while (ct + m <= 5);
    return 0;
}
```

For all permutations, try using bit operations.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of slightly customized probems, the best way is to get back to old school recursion and implement the recursive function to give the output.

Here is an example solution.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int n=5;
int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int vis[5]; //same size as arr[]
int m=3;
int ans[3];

void gen(int total_taken) {
    if(total_taken == m) {
        //found one permutation
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++) cout<<ans[i];
        cout<<endl;
        return;
    }    

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        if(vis[i]==0) {
            vis[i]=1;
            ans[total_taken] = arr[i];
            gen(total_taken+1);
            vis[i]=0;
        }    
    }
}

int main()
{
    //init n,m,ans[],arr[],vis[]
    gen(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Ayon Nahiyan's solution is the best way because this kind of customized problem. But if you only need for this specific case (you need to take 3 and get all their permutation) and also need to use `next_permutation` my code below is work (But, this code will give you difficulties if you want to change the "3" part)

```
#include <iostream>

#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int arr[3];
    int m=3;

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<5;j++){
            for(int k=j+1;k<5;k++){
                arr[0]=a[i];
                arr[1]=a[j];
                arr[2]=a[k];
                do {
                    for(int i=0;i<m;i++) {
                        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
                    }
                    cout<<endl;
                } while(next_permutation(arr, arr+m));
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Explanation:**

the code above simply just get all combination of 3 from your array and permute it using `next_permutation`